# Não consigo visualizar o realce das perguntas favoritas de acordo com o brilho

Tags: suporte, layout

Eu alterno o brilho do meu computador várias vezes por dia ou semana de acordo fatores como: janela aberta/fechada, persiana, nuvens etc.

Eu alterno através de um botão do monitor "Light View". Tem opções como: "normal", "day text", "day movie", "day photo", "night movie", "night photo".

Notei que de acordo com a configuração, não dá pra notar o realce das perguntas favoritas. O realce fica muito fraco.

Não dá pra mostrar essa diferença com printscreen, por isso tirei duas fotos.

**Normal**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Day Movie**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Acredito que não tenha muito o que fazer sobre, deve ser problema do monitor mesmo, mas não teria como colocar uma cor que desse pra notar o realce que não fosse afetada pela configuração do monitor? (Não que acho que vão fazer porque apenas uma pessoa pediu).

Comment: Eu acho bem difícil também, é comum eu nem perceber que tem um destaque.

Comment: Esse é um problema sério de usabilidade. Tanto que para situações mais críticas, se usam hachuras (texturas com padrão repetitivo), e não somente cores. Inclusive porque cores podem ser problemáticas para quem tem alguma limitação visual. O ideal é sempre ter as duas coisas: cor + diferença visível por intensidade.

Comment: Eu iria mais longe, cor as vezes dá certo outras não, seria legal um icone como uma bandeira, ou uma estrela, sei que parece bobo, mas acho mais intuitivo. Aqui pra mim aparece normal, mas é realmente devido ao monitor.

Comment: Eu tenho o meu "black" mas fui ver e é bem verdade, nem se repara e eu não uso a configuração normal do monitor.

Comment: Há vários hacks e workarounds postados nas respostas. Queria é ver um posicionamento oficial acerca disso.

Answer (score 8):

Você pode mudar o realce pelo lado do usuário instalando uma extensão e escrevendo seu próprio código.

Exemplos de extensões de userscript são Tampermonkey e Greasemonkey.

Um exemplo de código de realce:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         New highlight
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Modificando a cor de destaque da página inicial do SOPT
// @author       You
// @run-at       document-end
// @match        http://pt.stackoverflow.com/
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

window.onload = function () {
    $(".tagged-interesting").css("background-color","#ffccaa");
};
```

Não ficou a coisa mais bonita do mundo, mas tá bem destacado:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Brinque com o valor rgb onde está `"#ffccaa"` e ache a cor que melhor lhe agrada.

Comment: Lembrando que em quase todos os browsers comuns há extensões até mais simples, para injetar CSS próprio em sites específicos. Se for só pra isso, compensa.

Comment: Copyright @Math 2016

Comment: Math é necessário mesmo onload quando esta usando `@run-at       document-end`?

Comment: Não tinha reparado no run-at antes, retirando o run-at funcionou aqui, tirando o onload (e mantendo o run-at) não. Tem alguma sugestão? PS: pus um console.log e ele log-ou corretamente

Comment: @Math talvez criar um style dinamico, com javascript ou jquery. Vou testar aqui tambem.

Comment: Pelo que li requer `Greasemonkey 0.9.8+`, mas eu não sei a compatibilidade quanto ao tampermonkey

Comment: Eu ia editar a sua mas aproveitei a viajem XD http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5477/3635

Comment: Sem problemas, é bem diferente então cabe bem como nova resposta mesmo. Ficou muito bom, não tinha pensado naquela questão. Parabéns ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Fica aqui mais uma extensão que eu uso e já tem temas para vários sites como este, google, facebook, etc.

É [Stylish](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=pt-PT) e vou buscar aqui os temas: https://userstyles.org/styles/browse/stackoverflow

Eu uso esse tema, que por acaso até já contribui por causa de ajustes no chat:

[Stack Overflow Dark theme for Stylish](https://github.com/StylishThemes/StackOverflow-Dark):

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Answer (score 5):

Baseado no exemplo do [@Math](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5406/3635)

Observe a variável `bgColor`, troque pela cor desejada, sendo hexadecimal, rgb ou rgba (ou qualquer coisa que o CSS do teu browser aceite)

> Testado no <kbd>tampermonkey 4.2.5291</kbd>

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Highlight
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  highlight new posts
// @author       Guilherme Nascimento
// @match        http://pt.stackoverflow.com/
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function(doc) {
    'use strict';

    var bgColor = '#FCA'; //Troque pela cor desejada

    function trigger() {
        var s = doc.createElement("style");
        s.textContent = '.tagged-interesting {' +
                        '     background-color: ' + bgColor + ' !important;' +
                        '}';

        doc.head.appendChild(s);
    }

    if (/^(interactive|complete)$/i.test(doc.readyState)) {
        trigger();
    } else {
        doc.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', trigger);
    }
})(document);
```

**Resultado**

[image: Exemplo refresh e destaque das perguntas]

### Detalhes

A diferença é que ao invés de setar o `.css` no elemento direto, o script cria uma tag `<style>`, assim se aparecer novas perguntas sem repaginar o destaque irá funcionar também e como conversei com o @Math, o `@run-at` parece não funcionar, ou talvez fosse um conflito, todavia troquei `onload` e `@run-at` por uma função chamada `ready` que verifica o DOM da página foi processado, assim torna relativamente mais rápido para injetar o style.

Comment: Bom script, aplicando o estilo pras novas perguntas sem refresh da página.

Comment: @Math graças a ti, só adaptei :) ... eu nem sabia usar o tampermonkey, seu script me orientou.

Comment: E eu não sabia usar o tampermonkey, o [script do onosendai](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3977/3117) que me orientou hehehe

Answer (score 2):

Há muito tempo sinto incômodo com as cores nas listagens de perguntas.

Aqui a home page, por exemplo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Removi as linhas mais abaixo propositalmente para representar melhor a sensação.

As linhas divisórias que ficam mais abaixo da altura dos olhos esmaecem e desaparecem por terem cores muito fracas.

Sempre tolerei maas de vez em quando ainda incomoda. Então resolvi instalar uma extensão chrome. 
Instalei o primeiro que apareceu no google: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/care-your-eyes/fidmpnedniahpnkeomejhnepmbdamlhl?hl=en

Ativei cores diferentes e ficou assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ok, está horrível. Parece aqueles sites de 1997, mas está bem mais agradável de ler por estar mais legível devido aos contrastes. E fiz apenas para testes.

A extensão em si não ajuda muito mas quebra um galho para quem está com preguiça de criar uma extensão.

Pelo menos tem um shortcut CTRL + Q que ativa e desativa. Então fica bem fácil ligar e desligar.

Uma observação curiosa, eu uso duplo monitor. Ambos de mesmo modelo. 
Recentemente a minha placa de vídeo deu pau e estou usando a placa de vídeo onboard a qual tem conector DVI e VGA. No monitor que está conectado no DVI não há esse problema das linhas que vão sumindo. Mas no monitor conectado via VGA sim.

Parece que é devido ao tipo do conector. Se for VGA, provavelmente tem esse "problema".